swift Screen Time API Parent and child connect
Do we need a server to use the Screen Time API?
I want to create an app to control a child's device. As I understand it, I need to follow this logic:
I have one app for both the child and the parent.
For the child, I request authorization with the following code:
try await AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .child)

For the parent, I show functions like:
familyActivityPicker

Are these settings automatically applied to the child's device, or do I need to send a silent push notification to apply the new settings? Additionally, how can I get statistics from the child's device to the parent's device?

Welcome to SO.  Given that you have had no advice in 5 days you might want to post some code of things you have tried to give people an idea of what you are trying to do.
